# How can I get the ID from one model and pass it to another one? Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a two models like so :

```
class Entity(models.Model):
contact = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=True)
vat_registration = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=False, null=True)
street_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=True)
street_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
post_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=True)
country = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=240, blank=False, null=True)

class Invoices(models.Model):
invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=False, null=True)
invoice_date = models.DateField()
invoice_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=True)
client_ref = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=True)
supplier = models.ForeignKey(Suppliers, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
net_amount = models.FloatField()
vat_paid = models.FloatField()
vat_reclaimed = models.FloatField()
invoice_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=True) 
entity_name = models.ForeignKey(Entity, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have a page where I input some data from invoices and I would like to link the invoice which is entered to the company to which it belongs to.

Below is my (not working views.py):

```
def claim_details(request):                                         #save the invoice onto DB
form = forms.SaveInvoice(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        inv = Entity.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
        instance.entity_name = inv[0]
        print(instance)
        instance.save()
        return redirect('accounts:claim')
else:
    form = forms.SaveInvoice()
args = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'dashboard/claim_details.html', args)
```

I am trying to include the id from the Entity to the Invoice which is saved.

Any idea ?

I need to add that I see the field entity_name in the admin dashboard but the value is NULL. I would like it to be equal to the entity to which I enter the invoices for.

I am pulling my hair and don't really understand what should be put in the if statement. The inv variable returns a queryset with the id of the Entity but I really don't know how to have it to save when submitting the form ... your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right, but not quite right. You already have the field as a foreign key, hence you need not worry about getting id. Just get the whole Entity object you want to link to and pass it in entity_name, Django will automatically assign the id to that field. In case you want to view the id, use `object.pk`. Pk as in primary key. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do I pass in the entity id in the following code ? 

            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            inv = Entity.objects.all()
            instance.entity_name = inv[???]

By hard coding a value (0 or 1) in the inv[} field I can get a different entity but how can I make this generic so depending on the entity, the value changes ? I have trouble imderstanding how to parse the value in there ... 
Thanks.

Comment: InvoiceObject= Invoices.objects.get(pk=1) # based on what you want.
instance.entity_name=invoiceObject
@bobomichel

Answer (score 0):

Since `entity_name` is a [foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) you don't need to bother yourself with assigning record ID directly - as was mentioned, Django will do this for you. Simply use this:

```
inv = Entity.objects.first()
instance.entity_name = inv
instance.save()
```

Also, note two things:

- as for now, you're fetching any first record from `Entity` table and basically all invoices will be bound to same `Entite`. Perhaps you wanted to filter this by user: `Entity.objects.filter(contact=request.user).first`
- `entity_name` have set `on_delete` argument to `CASCADE`. This means that when related `Entity` is deleted, you'll lose invoce as well. Possibly you want to keep invoices as a historical data no matter if related `Entity` is deleted.